# PHP and Android GCM push notification - How to store users

Tags: php, android, zend-framework, push-notification

I have my Android client application that wait for a push message from the GCM Google server... on the server side, my web must store the registration ID of the device, in order to send the push notification to this specific device (calling the GCM Service with a specific PHP class). 
The question is, how can I refresh the registration Id of the device every time It is registreted on the Google GCM servers? How can I associate to each users on the web app to a specific registration Id of the android app?

Answer (score 0):

You can use PHpmyadmin tool to creat the data base and use the php script to open,store registration Id  and close the db.

Comment: Ok, but my doubt is about the registration ID... the Android application must every time updates the Id send It to the web app?